# Super CSV and Grouping Separators

Tags: java, bigdecimal, supercsv

We are trying to read a file that contains numbers in the following format: `123.456,78` ([according to Wikipedia this is usual for some countries - e.g. Germany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)).

Super CSV is configured to parse the column as BigDecimal: `new ParseBigDecimal(new DecimalFormatSymbols(GERMANY))`.

That works well for numbers below 1k, but the grouping separator is not handled properly: `'1.999,00' could not be parsed as a BigDecimal`.

I've seen that it is possible to write a [custom cell processor](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_new_cell_processor.html), but perhaps someone knows if there is an easier way or if this is a known bug in Super CSV.

**UPDATE:**

**Super CSV has integrated that feature and released it with version 2.2.0. It will work for all grouping separators that are supplied via the `DecimalFormatSymbols` parameter.**

Comment: It's common to use a comma for decimal part in most languages that use Latin characters except English and Malay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParseBigDecimal` (prior to 2.2.0) only uses the decimal separator from the supplied `DecimalFormatSymbols` (not the grouping separator). It's not a bug, just a limitation of the current implementation.

You can chain a `StrReplace` before the `ParseBigDecimal` (i.e. replace `"."` with `""`) and that should fix your problem (quickly).

I think that `ParseBigDecimal` should actually do this for you. ***UPDATE: And so does it since version 2.2.0***.

Like you said, you can always write your own cell processor too :)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. seems like a great opportunity to contribute something to open source this evening :-)